How to simply read directory content by handling errors
I try to learn rust, and I block on a simple task, do a directory listing with catching errors without panicking.
I found only example which drop all errors.
This is my current code
The first part catch error, but then I cannot do anything with entry (got compile errors)
The second part works, but errors is not catched
use std::fs;
fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("/tmp/rust");
    if paths.is_err() {
        /* THIS IS DISPLAYED WHEN ERROR */
        println!("GOT ERROR 1");
        return ;
    }
    for entry in paths {
        /* CANNOT DO ANYTHING with entry */
        /* if entry.is_err() {} do not work */
            /*println!("Name: {}", entry.filename());*/
            /*println!("Name: {}", entry.path().display());*/
    }

    /* THIS WORK */
    if let Ok(paths) = fs::read_dir("/tmp/rust") {
        for entry in paths {
            println!("Name: {}", entry.unwrap().path().display());
        }
    } else {
        /* THIS IS NEVER DISPLAYED */
        println!("GOT ERROR")
    }
}

EDIT: working version
use std::fs;

fn scan(p: &str) -> i32 {
    println!("SCAN {}", p);
    let paths = fs::read_dir(p);
    if paths.is_err() {
        println!("GOT ERROR 1");
        return 1;
    }
    for entry in paths.unwrap() {
            if entry.is_err() {
                println!("GOT ERROR 2");
                continue
            }
            let e = entry.unwrap();
            //println!("Name: {}", e.path().display());
            let meta = e.metadata();
            let m = meta.unwrap();
            if m.is_dir() {
                println!("Dir: {}", e.path().display());
                let pa = e.path();
                let st = pa.to_str();
                if st == None {
                    println!("Name is not UTF8");
                    continue
                }
                let s = st.unwrap();
                scan(s);
            } else {
                println!("Name: {}", e.path().display());
            }
    }
    0
}

fn main() {
    scan("/tmp/rust");
}

Does am I right to said it is safe to use unwrap since I tested is_err before ?
Does is there is a more clean/rust way of doing it ?
Thanks

The first error is displayed, but the second is not. Because you're returning after the println!("GET ERROR 1");. Also, note for entry in paths is wrong at least the naming of the variables imply something else. Your (first) paths is a io::Result<ReadDir>, not a ReadDir so entry in the for loop is the ReadDir, that you then can iterate to get the entries

For your last example, the "THIS IS NEVER DISPLAYED" comment is wrong: in this playground, we see the "GOT ERROR" message.

Thanks, yes removing the return lead to a successfull GOT ERROR.
But I still fail to access .filename or metadata without unwrap()

Yes, that's the point of Result you need to handle the error in some way to be able to access the data, unwrap is one of them, but you can also use any of the other methods of Result or even pattern match on it.

To add on to the other answer, if you want to catch the errors yourself instead of relying on unwrap to panic, you can either use match or let ... else.  Since you don't use the error value at all, you can use let ... else like so:
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let Ok(paths) = fs::read_dir("/tmp/rust") else {
        println!("GOT ERROR 1");
        return;
    };

    for entry in paths {
        let Ok(entry) = entry else {
            println!("GOT ERROR 2");
            return;
        };

        println!("Name: {}", entry.file_name().to_string_lossy());
        println!("Name: {}", entry.path().display());
    }
}

However, you can also just unwrap everywhere if you are fine letting panics happen.  This makes your code a lot shorter.
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/tmp/rust").unwrap() {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();

        println!("Name: {}", entry.file_name().to_string_lossy());
        println!("Name: {}", entry.path().display());
    }
}


Adding to @cdhowie's answer you can also have main return a Result and use the question mark operator to handle the errors:
use std::fs;
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/tmp/rust")? {
        let entry = entry?;

        println!("Name: {}", entry.file_name().to_string_lossy());
        println!("Name: {}", entry.path().display());
    }
    Ok(())
}

Playground
A couple of notes:

You need to return Ok(()) from main to tell the compiler that everything went fine.
When used in main, this will exit and print a message in case of error like unwrap.
However when used in another function, this will simply return the error from the function and let the caller handle it, which is closer to what would happen in real code with multiple functions.


To expand on what has already been mentioned in the comments:
In your first version, paths is still an io::Result when you try to iterate over it with for entry in paths. Since io::Result does implement IntoIter, this works (it extracts the single ReadDir value out of the Result), but is probably not what you want. Replace with for entry in paths.unwrap() to iterate directly over the ReadDir contained.
Note that entry will also be a Result that you will have to unwrap somehow before calling e.g. .filename() on it.
Your second version looks fine and should be working. If you are running both versions at the same time, the return in the error case of version 1 explains why you never see the error output of version 2.
